# How to handle WPF MenuItem Commands in a Caliburn.Micro ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

My WPF application have a layout page with the following code:

```xml
/* /Views/ShellView.xaml */
<DockPanel>
  <!-- Global Main menu, always visible -->
  <Menu IsMainMenu="true" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <MenuItem Header="_File">
      <MenuItem Command="Save"/>
      <MenuItem Header="_Save As..."/>
      <Separator/>
      <MenuItem Header="_Exit"/>
    </MenuItem>
  </Menu>

  <!-- The window's main content. It contains forms that the user might want to save -->
  <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Since I'm using Caliburn.Micro, I've also implemented the corresponding view model:

```cs
/* /ViewModels/ShellViewModel.cs */
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object> {
  // Control logic to manage ActiveItem
}
```

My objective is to implement an handler for the `Save` command, which I assume is triggered whenever the user click on the corresponding `MenuItem` or press `CTRL + S`.

In standard WPF I would add a `CommandBinding` tag in `ShellView.xaml` (as shown in [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-enable-a-command)) to route the event to an handler I would implement within `ShellView.xaml.cs`. However, for the sake of respecting Caliburn.Micro's MVVM conventions, I want my logic to stay within the view model class.

I've looked into Caliburn.Micro's documentation but the closest thing I've found to commands were [Actions](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/actions).

How can I implement that?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Here is a demo caliburn micro screw view change, I'll add a command to it for you to see. https://github.com/juanvan/ViewChangerAsync

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a shorter solution. On class inheriting `ViewAware`, the protected virtual method `onViewReady` is called with the view object when the view is ready.

So in my view model I can just override it like so:

```cs
protected override void OnViewReady(object view) {
    base.OnViewReady(view);

    ShellView shellView = (ShellView)view;
    shellView.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.SaveAs, SaveAsCommandHandler));
}
```

With the view object, I can add a new `CommandBinding` instance by specifying the specific command and the handler.

The handler can be define within the view model class:

```cs
private void SaveAsCommandHandler(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) {
    this.CurrentForm.SaveAs();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution isnt short!!

You need to create a dependency (here is GestureMenuItem)

in xaml file

---

```
 xmlns:common="clr-namespace:Common.Caliburn"
 :
 :
  <Menu IsMainMenu="true" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
     <common:GestureMenuItem x:Name="Save" Key="S" Modifiers="Ctrl" Header="_Save"/>
```

---

in ActionMessageCommand.cs file

---

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Caliburn.Micro;

namespace Common.Caliburn
{
    public class ActionMessageCommand : ActionMessage, ICommand
    {
        static ActionMessageCommand()
        {
            EnforceGuardsDuringInvocation = true;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            
        }

        void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
        {
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    }
}
```

---

in GestureMenuItem.cs file

---

```
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

namespace Common.Caliburn
{
    public class GestureMenuItem : MenuItem
    {
        public override void EndInit()
        {
            Interaction.GetTriggers(this).Add(ConstructTrigger());

            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(InputGestureText))
                InputGestureText = BuildInputGestureText(Modifiers, Key);

            base.EndInit();
        }

        private static readonly IEnumerable<ModifierKeys> ModifierKeysValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ModifierKeys)).Cast<ModifierKeys>().Except(new [] { ModifierKeys.None });

        private static readonly IDictionary<ModifierKeys, string> Translation = new Dictionary<ModifierKeys, string>
        {
            { ModifierKeys.Control, "Ctrl" }
        };

        private static string BuildInputGestureText(ModifierKeys modifiers, Key key)
        {
            var result = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var val in ModifierKeysValues)
                if ((modifiers & val) == val)
                    result.Append((Translation.ContainsKey(val) ? Translation[val] : val.ToString()) + " + ");

            result.Append(key);

            return result.ToString();
        }

        private TriggerBase<FrameworkElement> ConstructTrigger()
        {
            var trigger = new InputBindingTrigger();

            trigger.GlobalInputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding { Modifiers = Modifiers, Key = Key });

            var command = new ActionMessageCommand { MethodName = Name };
            Command = command;
            trigger.Actions.Add(command);

            return trigger;
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ModifiersProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Modifiers", typeof(ModifierKeys), typeof(GestureMenuItem), new PropertyMetadata(default(ModifierKeys)));

        public ModifierKeys Modifiers
        {
            get { return (ModifierKeys)GetValue(ModifiersProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ModifiersProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty KeyProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Key", typeof(Key), typeof(GestureMenuItem), new PropertyMetadata(default(Key)));

        public Key Key
        {
            get { return (Key)GetValue(KeyProperty); }
            set { SetValue(KeyProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

---

in InputBindingTrigger.cs file

---

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;
using Caliburn.Micro;

namespace Common.Caliburn
{
    public class InputBindingTrigger : TriggerBase<FrameworkElement>, ICommand
    {
        public InputBindingTrigger()
        {
            GlobalInputBindings = new BindableCollection<InputBinding>();
            LocalInputBindings = new BindableCollection<InputBinding>();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty LocalInputBindingsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("LocalInputBindings", typeof(BindableCollection<InputBinding>), typeof(InputBindingTrigger), new PropertyMetadata(default(BindableCollection<InputBinding>)));

        public BindableCollection<InputBinding> LocalInputBindings
        {
            get { return (BindableCollection<InputBinding>)GetValue(LocalInputBindingsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LocalInputBindingsProperty, value); }
        }

        public BindableCollection<InputBinding> GlobalInputBindings
        {
            get { return (BindableCollection<InputBinding>)GetValue(GlobalInputBindingProperty); }
            set { SetValue(GlobalInputBindingProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty GlobalInputBindingProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("GlobalInputBinding", typeof(BindableCollection<InputBinding>), typeof(InputBindingTrigger), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            foreach (var binding in GlobalInputBindings.Union(LocalInputBindings))
                binding.Command = this;

            AssociatedObject.Loaded += delegate
            {
                var window = GetWindow(AssociatedObject);

                foreach (var binding in GlobalInputBindings)
                    window.InputBindings.Add(binding);

                foreach (var binding in LocalInputBindings)
                    AssociatedObject.InputBindings.Add(binding);
            };

            base.OnAttached();
        }

        private Window GetWindow(FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
        {
            if (frameworkElement is Window)
                return frameworkElement as Window;

            var parent = frameworkElement.Parent as FrameworkElement;

            return GetWindow(parent);
        }

        bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            InvokeActions(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

and in ShellViewModel.cs, using the convention name of Caliburn

```
    public void Save()
    {
        //some code here
    }
```

Comment: This is an Amazing answer, but did he want gestures?

Comment: so i have no other solution without breaking the MVVM model..